# ComboBox or Mahapps dropdownbutton doesn't update when once opened

Tags: wpf, combobox, itemssource, mahapps.metro

I've create a dummy WPF application with a dropdownbutton from Mahapps (called ddbTest) and a button (called btnAddExtra)

Update: The same issue occurs when using a combobox instead of a dropdownbutton.

This is the code behind:

```
public List<string> MyItems;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyItems = new List<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        MyItems.Add("Value" + i.ToString());

    }
    ddbTest.ItemsSource = MyItems;
}

private void btnAddExtra_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyItems.Add("Value 50" );
    ddbTest.ItemsSource = MyItems;
}
```

If I press the button first and then open the dropdownbutton then 'Value 50' is added.

Restart the project

If I open and close the dropdownbutton first and the press the button and then open the dropdownbutton. Now 'Value 50' is not present.

Any idea's on how to fix this?

Comment: You set `ItemsSource` to same collection (with extra item) so value does not change. Instead of `List<T>` use `ObservableCollection<T>`, which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, and then you don't need to update `ItemsSouce` just add/remove items to the collection

Comment: For this dummy project that works. In the real project I'm working with I Set the itemsSource to the Items of a MenuItem. The problem is that there are submaps under this dropdownbutton. I could make an observablecollection of this but then changes on a deeper level will not be seen.